# gzopen function does no exists after I have changed my PHP setup

Tags: php, gzip

With the new PHP 5.4 `gzopen` function does not exist.
All other Zlib functions I need exist except for `gzopen`.

I did a test and it shows me this

> ```
>  Zlib exists 
>
>  gzopen does not exists
> ```

```
<?php
echo (extension_loaded('zlib')) ? 'Zlib exists' : 'Zlib does not exist';
echo '<br />';
echo (function_exists('gzopen')) ? 'gzopen exists' : 'gzopen does not exist';
?>
```

The result of `var_dump(get_extension_funcs('zlib'));` is:

```
array(25) {
    [0]=> string(10) "readgzfile"
    [1]=> string(8) "gzrewind"
    [2]=> string(7) "gzclose"
    [3]=> string(5) "gzeof"
    [4]=> string(6) "gzgetc"
    [5]=> string(6) "gzgets"
    [6]=> string(7) "gzgetss"
    [7]=> string(6) "gzread"
    [8]=> string(8) "gzopen64"
    [9]=> string(10) "gzpassthru"
    [10]=> string(8) "gzseek64"
    [11]=> string(8) "gztell64"
    [12]=> string(7) "gzwrite"
    [13]=> string(6) "gzputs"
    [14]=> string(6) "gzfile"
    [15]=> string(10) "gzcompress"
    [16]=> string(12) "gzuncompress"
    [17]=> string(9) "gzdeflate"
    [18]=> string(9) "gzinflate"
    [19]=> string(8) "gzencode"
    [20]=> string(8) "gzdecode"
    [21]=> string(11) "zlib_encode"
    [22]=> string(11) "zlib_decode"
    [23]=> string(20) "zlib_get_coding_type"
    [24]=> string(12) "ob_gzhandler"
}
```

Has anyone else had the same problem with PHP 5.4?  How did you fix it?

Comment: What are the configure flags for your build? (see phpinfo)

Comment: Please execute this: var_dump(get_extension_funcs('zlib')); And post the results here.

Comment: The question was about the `Configure Command` section, not repeating the zlib state.

Comment: http://www.linode.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=4836%3E
Perhaps that will be of some help. I am trying to find you a more concrete answer.

Comment: *Do you have the same problem for you with PHP 5.4?* — SO is not the place to take polls.

Comment: Recent versions of zlib #define gzopen to gzopen64 on 64-bit OSes, and the PHP zlib module does not compensate for this, so the PHP gzopen function also gets renamed to gzopen64.

Comment: I don't really have a fix for you. Some (Ubuntu Karmic?) are building zlib with -DZLIB_INTERNAL=1 so both gzopen() and gzopen64() coexist in the library, which would also help the PHP zlib extension keep gzopen, but it's a hack and may go away in future versions of zlib.

Comment: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53829