# php zlib gzopen not exists

Tags: php, zlib

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and php 5.5.9-1ubuntu4 (cli) (built: Apr  9 2014 17:08:27)

```
var_dump(extension_loaded('zlib')); => true
var_dump(function_exists('gzread')); => true
var_dump(function_exists('gzclose')); => true
```

But

```
var_dump(function_exists('gzopen')); => false
```

What's wrong ?

Thank you for ideas

Comment: It looks like a Ubuntu specific problem. Does the function `gzopen64` exist if you call `function_exists` ?

Comment: Yes, `gzopen64` exists...

Comment: You can use it as a workaround if you need it for now. Consider compiling PHP manually on your own, by using the latest sources from php.net. Without forgetting to pass the argument `--with-zlib=yes` to the `./configure` script before compiling. To see the *Configure Command* of your current PHP build, check the phpinfo().

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551504/gzopen-function-does-no-exists-after-i-have-changed-my-php-setup

Answer (score 4):

This is a known bug in PHP 5.3+ when compiled against certain versions of Zlib.

There is a [bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53829) from 2011 with several proposed fixes.  However, all of the fixes will require you to recompile PHP.

Instead, you can use `gzopen64`.  In theory, it works exactly the same way.